# How to export base-64 encoded X.509 .cer certificate to file directly from Chrome/Edge browsers?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to renew a website certificate and for this purpose, I would like to compare 2 `.cer` certificates side-by-side. However, I am having issues with exporting the currently used certificate from Chrome or Edge.
It would seem that with the last Chrome or Edge updates (I am now on Chrome 107.0.5304 and Edge 107.0.1418) on Windows 11 OS, you no longer have the ability to export a website certificate to file using a format of "`base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer)`".

It used to work like this:

- open the website in Chrome
- click the "lock" padlock near the URL, then click "connection is secure"
- on Details tab of the certificate, click "copy to file"
- on the certificate export wizard, you could choose the "`base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer)`" format

Now I am seeing in the latest Chrome 107.0.5304 and Edge 107.0.1418 versions on Windows 11 OS that `.cer` export is no longer available from the browser:

- open the website in Chrome
- click the "lock" padlock near the URL, then click "connection is secure", then click "certificate is valid"
- a new Certificate Viewer modal window is displayed, go to Details tab, click "Export" button
- there is no longer a file type `.cer` available for export, and as well the certificate export wizard is no longer used

Any ideas on how to export the website certificate in `base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer)` format directly from Chrome or Edge would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's still there for the same Chrome version on Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

The output should be the same `.cer` and `.crt` are just extensions for the same file, but `.cer` is not used a lot. The content of the file can be either Base 64 encoded or DER encoded. Since you said `base-64 encoded X.509` I am guessing that the current option: `base-64 ascii (.pem, .crt)` provides you with exactly the same content as `base-64 encoded X.509` previously did.

More information on what types of encoding there are and how to convert them can for example be read here: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/how-to-convert-a-certificate-to-the-correct-format/

Comment: thanks for your comment! This is what i was guessing as well, but i want to be sure that the current option Base-64 ascii (.crt) would result in the same content as an old base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer) used to give. I dont seem to find for what reason they decided not to give the option to export .cer anymore.

Comment: somewhere along the way, either Win11 or the browsers (Chrome, Edge etc) decided to replace the SSL certificate option "Copy to File" and corresponding Certificate Export Wizard where you could choose to export in .cer format with an "Export" option, where you can only choose to save as .pem or .crt format.  If the certificate sits for example on a reverse proxy as Apache, where it's installed as .cer, the browsers will only export it as .crt

Answer (score 1):

you can open the .crt file in windows and the familiar export wizard will appear.